# What (test) should I do to measure association between two ordinal variables but some cells were found to equal zero when crosstabulated?

Tags: ordinal-data, likert, association-measure

I've been scouring and asking on forums (such as this) and the web for answers as I'm trying to test the strength of the relationship between two ordinal variables from my questionnaire. I found after cross-tabing them, that there are some cells with zero values, which would cause them to fail assumptions for the tests mentioned in this [guideline](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/ordinal-association/). You can find the "assumptions" part at the bottom.

Combining the Neutral, Disagree and Strongly Disagree levels won't work either as some suggested, as you can see below, since there is a zero value across the 3 levels.

Also, after graphing my data I found that the relationship between these two ordinal variables is non-monotonic, which filters out some tests that people in previous forums recommended for me. Concerning this monotonic situation, someone said that I should instead use nominal-nominal association tests since ordinality doesn't matter when the relationship is non-monotonic. If this is the case, can someone suggest a specific test to use in my situation? Really urgently need some help for this. Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `some cells with zero values, which would cause them to fail assumptions` Why? Your guide paper is incorrect at that. Correlations (such as Spearman or Kendall) can tolerate empty cells.

Comment: Regarding nonmonotinic relationship: You may treat the variables as nominal and perform chi-square test of independence. Use Exact testing or Monte Carlo testing if there are low _expected_ frequencies. Also, you may still use Kendall correlation to measure the positive or negative dominant "trend" in the correlation (Kendall, unlike Spearman, does not _assume_ monotonic relationship).

Comment: I don't think I can use Fishers exact test as my variables don't seem to have a dichotomous relationship (attitude and behavior don't seem that dichotomous).Not sure about Monte carlo, it seems far less common as I can't find as much info about it. Plz correct me if I'm wrong about all the above that I've just said (Especially for the fishers exact test). You guys have said that Kendall can tolerate empty cells but why does this guideline say otherwise?: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/ordinal-association/
Also, if Kendall can in fact tolerate empty cells, should I use it for my case?

Comment: do you have more data - data on other variables ?  Also state your problem or hypotheses that you would want to test ?